# How to get ClaimsPrincipal from ADAL AuthenticationResult

Tags: azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

I'm using Azure Active Directory Authentication Library to sign-in users in a WPF application. After call to `AuthenticationContext.AcquireToken()` I get `AuthenticationResult` with some `UserInfo` but it does not provide a `ClaimsPrincipal` which my application uses. Also `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current` returns only an empty principal object with no claims populated in it. How do I get the `ClaimsPrincipal` for the signed-in user?

Comment: What kind of information do you need to retrieve from the ClaimsPrincipal ?

Comment: Have you tried to access  Thread.CurrentPrincipal ?

Comment: I need to access basic user info and all the claims for the user, the same ones that we get when we sign-in to AD through OAuth. `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` also contains an empty GenericPrincipal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AuthenticationResult.AccessToken is a JWT token that represents the user. You can use http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/5.0.0-rc1-211161024 to read the token and create a claims principal. the api for the JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken takes a TokenValidationParameters that can be used to scope validation.

All that said, depending on what you need (perhaps you don't need a ClaimsPrincipal), you might want to have a look at the AuthenticationResult.UserInfo property.

Comment: Thanks Brent, right now I'm looking into `UserInfo` and creating a `ClaimsPrincipal` from it but it doesn't include everything. I will try the nuget you referenced.

Comment: Note the 5.x version of S.IM.Tokens.Jwt is prerelease and will support 4.5.1 and corefx. The 4.x is release quality.

Comment: I'm struggling with this too, working on my first WPF project to use MS.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory. I've found that the `UserInfo` is null. Does that mean I've assigned the wrong values to the AuthenticateContext() constructor or the AcquireTokenAsync() call?

Comment: Really help me to proceed. Thanks @BrentSchmaltz